# Android Studio does not Reopen last project on startup in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.1

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 android Android Studio 2.1. In my android Studio **Reopen last project on startup** is already checked but it never opens my last project automatically, each and every time I need to choose the project path.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Mac, the solution was close the Android studio from the menu instead of red cross.

[image]